# MapMyIndia Flutter integration Android is working but in iOS map not loading

Tags: ios, flutter, mapmyindia-api

flutter mapmyInidia working fine in android, But iOS i am getting like
 `"onMapError : AUTHENTICATION FAILED"`

`MapmyIndiaAccountManager.setMapSDKKey(Prefs.ACCESS_TOKEN),  MapmyIndiaAccountManager.setRestAPIKey(Prefs.REST_API_KEY),  MapmyIndiaAccountManager.setAtlasClientId(Prefs.ATLAS_CLIENT_ID),  MapmyIndiaAccountManager.setAtlasClientSecret(Prefs.ATLAS_CLIENT_SECRET)`

i have added above all key, still map is not loading in iOS, Anyone know the steps to integrating on flutter(iOS)?